What is the mechanical equivalent of an electronic AND gate?
Electronically, AND gates are commonly composed of CMOS transistors.
What is a mechanical AND gate that produces the same "true if the two inputs are true; otherwise false" output?

See also https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/86/16835

Are you looking for a single canonical answer (there isn't one; there are many ways to do this non-electrically), or just a list of answers?

@Hearth I'm looking for the answer where the output of mechanical stuff can be the next input of another similar mechanical gates.

@MuhammadIkhwanPerwira Again, are you looking for the answer, or an answer? Because there is no "the answer", just a bunch of "an answer"s.

The anti tamper mechanism on outlets is an AND gate, both gates must be pressed before the shutters will slide out of the way.
This is achieved most commonly by needing to push the both shutters out of the way of a catch before they will slide or rotate out of the way. Pushing on one means that the other will block the movement.
Another example would be a series mechanical connection. For example in a manual transmission car the clutch and the gearbox are ANDed, the clutch must be engaged AND the gearbox must be in a gear before the engine can apply torque to the wheels.
Of course De Morgan laws apply here, if either the clutch is disengaged OR the gearbox is in neutral the engine cannot provide torque to the wheels.

There seem to be many simple examples when you think about it, for example, an exterior door with a storm door:  Any two gates in series.

Pneumatic systems can be purely mechanical and a wide range of pneumatic logic gates and timers are available.

Figure 1. Image source: LearnChannel-TV.

In the example above logic inputs are applied to each side with the logic output being at the top. Positive pressure is a logic 1 and no pressure is logic 0.
A floating "spool" can move left or right inside the device and can block one of the inlet ports at a time.


In switch position 1 air is applied to the left input only. This pushes the spool to the right and prevents air reaching the output.
Same as 1, but with air in from the right.
Air has been applied to both sides. The left side has shut off. (This may be due to slight differences in pressure, tolerances in manufacturing or that the spool was already in that position when the right input was pressurised.) Now air from the right can get past the right end of the spool and set the output to logic 1.
The opposite of 3.


When I was working with pneumatics, these were known as double-check valves (Westinghouse No 19?) and in an analog sense, they would allow the lowest source pressure to pass through to the destination. There was also a version which allowed the higher of two pressures to pass (Westinghouse No 15?) and this would be the equivalent of an OR gate (I guess that placing the red seals on the outside instead of the inside of the spool's faces would have the required effect).

In hydraulics, the equivalent valves would be a low-side shuttle or high-side shuttle. For the original question about an AND condition of "pressure is needed at ports 1 and 3 for flow to move to port 2", many logic elements like this can work.

boring answer :- A door lock. Ask Mr Yale

true, a lock will only open if all pins are engaged(wording?) right.

Yup, you simultaneously have to press the right tumblers and not press the wrong ones.

AND better if you have multiple locks on your door. The deadbold AND your door chain AND your Yale lock have to be undone to open the door.

Steve Mould on YouTube built a water computer using siphons that does simple binary addition: Water computer (YouTube). If you go to the 2:45 minute mark, he specifically demonstrates an AND gate. The AND gates work by triggering the siphon with two volumes of water, whereas just a single or no volume of water will fail to trigger it.
There's a game called Turing Tumble (Wikipedia) that is a mechanical computer using marbles and can supposedly do anything a modern computer can do given a large enough playfield. I don't have the game myself to build an AND gate, but here's a forum post with a couple of possible ways of doing it: https://community.turingtumble.com/t/and-gate-standard-size-simulator/1912/8
Finally, there's an educational toy(?) called Spintronics (Product site) (not to be confused with the field in physics) that allows the construction of mechanical circuits. Their website has some challenges/solutions, including building an AND gate. Here's a link to their solution in a simulator: https://simulator.spintronics.com/?linkID=15, although apparently, there are multiple other possible solutions.

A whippletree (also called a whiffletree) can be used as either an and or or gate.
Some interesting uses were:
The IBM Selectric typewriter
Some of the fire control for naval gunnery
and (my favorite load is balancing the load for drought animals.)
"The Engineer Guy" YouTube channel has a great video on it.

An illustration would be really nice.

If I had the artistic talent, I would have offered a diagram.
However like the video Bill Hammack (engineerguy.com) did on them
"The Whiffletree: A mechanical digital-to-analog converter"

In general, a "gate" will produce one of two output states for any combination of valid inputs.  If one used a whippletree with a "buffer" device that would snap to one position when the input was on one side of the midpoint, and snap to the other side when the input was on the other side of the midpoint, one could bias the output of a whippletree so that it would only pass the midpoint if all inputs were high, or so that it would pass the midpoint if any were high, and the combination of whippletree plus buffer would be an AND or OR gate, but I wouldn't call a non-buffered whippletree a gate.

A hydraulic or pneumatic system where two valves control fluid flow. Think of it like a garden hose with two valves in the line.

"... where tow series connected valves control the fluid flow" might describe it a little better.

The best example I know of is a chain across a road or pathway, with two padlocks "in series".  This is so that two different people, with two different keys, can unlock the chain and let themselves through.  The overall chain is "locked" (the road is impassible) if padlock #1 is locked, and padlock #2 is locked.
Or you can flip it on its head: the overall chain is unlocked — someone can get through — if padlock #1 is unlocked, or padlock #2 is unlocked.  (This is of course a real-world example of De Morgan's law in action.)
So then you can ask, how do you rig it up so that something is unlocked if padlock #1 is unlocked and padlock #2 is unlocked?  There's a device for that; it's used for locking out equipment when there are several people working on it and none of them want it to move or come back on if they're still working on it.  It looks like this:

lockout-tagout hasp.svg Wikimedia user RTCNCA, GFDL licence
You can see this device in action, with two padlocks, in this picture.
(And, De Morgan's law again, in that case, the thing is locked if padlock #1 is locked or padlock #2 is locked.)

I was going to post the same idea.  Wikimedia Commons' drawing of a 6-input AND gate in the form of a lockout has a suitable licence to include in the answer

@ChrisH Yes indeed, and I intended to — but (blush) I can never remember how to embed pictures in SE markdown, and I got distracted by something else before I could look it up and add that picture.

How does that look?

@ChrisH Thanks!  Tweaked.

One possibility would be a dual-coil relay:

Activate one coil, and the plunger will rise, but not enough to close the switch. But activate both coils, and the plunger rises enough to close the switch.
Of course the basic idea can work out the same without getting electricity involved. For example, you could use essentially the same mechanism, but change the coils to floats, and the switch to a valve. When there's liquid under both floats, the plunger is raised to open the valve, and allow liquid to flow.
